# How to disable new/edit/delete of SharePoint list/library views

Tags: list, list-view, libraries

In our SharePoint portal we have some custom views defined for list and libraries.

I have created the views using list event receiver. Now I need to disable the new/edit/delete views option from SharePoint so that no one can create, modify or delete the view for any of the lists.

How to achieve this? Any object model to achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating custom permission level.

```
using (SPWeb currentSite = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb)
{
    // create a new role definition and set base permissions
    SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = new SPRoleDefinition()
    {
    Name = "Custom Permission Level",
    BasePermissions = SPBasePermissions.AddListItems | SPBasePermissions.OpenItems |
        SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems | SPBasePermissions.EditListItems
    }; 

    // add the role definition
    currentSite.RoleDefinitions.Add(roleDefinition);
}
```

[Source](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2008/04/07/how-to-creating-a-custom-permission-level.aspx).

Using existing role definition:

```
public static void AddPrincipalRoleToSite(SPPrincipal entity, SPWeb web, string roleDef)
{
    SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(entity);
    SPRoleDefinitionCollection collRoles = web.RoleDefinitions;
    SPRoleDefinition oRoleDefinition = collRoles[roleDef];

    roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(oRoleDefinition);
    web.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jussi Palo: Instead of creating new role definition is that possible to set this permission to the existing role definition?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Jussi Palo: where we are using the role parameter, It seems there was some issue with this answer.

Comment: Actually the role parameter might not be needed (not at my machine so cannot test). Removed the parameter. Can you post the error, if you get some.

Comment: Error :Permission level cannot be found. for this line i am getting the issue. "SPRoleDefinition oRoleDefinition = collRoles[roleDef];"SPRoleDefinition oRoleDefinition = collRoles[roleDef];" i am calling method like this "AddPrincipalRoleToSite(web.CurrentUser, SPRoleType.Contributor, web, "ManagePersonalViews");"

Comment: I believe the last parameter should be your custom permission level, like "Custom Permission Level". That "ManagePersonalViews" is SPBasePermission that you group together to form an actual RoleDefinition.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should create your own [role defenition](http://mitsworld.wordpress.com/2009/09/03/creating-custom-role-definition-programmatically/) based on [SPBasePermissions enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx), in this defenition you should exclude following base permissions:

1. ManagePersonalViews - Create, change, and delete personal views of lists.
2. ManageLists - Create and delete lists, add or remove columns in a list, and add or remove public views of a list.

Then you should assigne this role defenition to user group which contains users that should not create views.

Comment: Do u have any coding sample for this?. Thanks in advance

Comment: for defenition creation you can look at first post that I provided. Do you need example how to assigne a new defenition to a user group by code?

Comment: my problem i have some set of cusomized user and group permission, so i am not able to create new user or role.Atleast i can remove the view related permisson from the site for all the user in the site.  Is that possible to do.

Comment: you can [break role inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535228.aspx)  only for your list, and configure groups in this list as you wish. These changes are not affected to other site and lists permissions.

Comment: :Don't we have option to remove the "ManagePersonalViews" permission from contributer(OOB)?

Comment: you can copy contribute role definition, and remove ManagePersonalViews base permission from a copy. Then you can remove contribute role from your group in list and add a new created role. if you customize contribute role you can break access to other lists.

Comment: If you create a new permission level that has all the capabilities of the contribute role definition - except for "Manage Lists" then contributors won't be able to "Create and Delete lists, add or remove columns in a list, or addor remove public views of a list".  It might work for folks whom you wish only to fill out forms or upload documents, however.  Otherwise, I reckon you'd have to create a new (not OOB) kind of permission.