# How to allow users to fill out forms in a form library, yet not create new views?

Tags: permissions, forms-library

In my forms library, I want users (who have contributor rights on the site) to be able to add forms and edit forms but not create new views.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I didn't at first find this here in SSE, I found it via Duck-Duck-Go.  [Here is the answer here in SSE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29802/how-to-disable-new-edit-delete-of-sharepoint-list-library-views).

I ended up creating a new set of permissions that did not have the "Manage Lists" List Permission, which is what allows for the managing of list views.  It disables `Create View`, `Modify view` from view menu in the ribbon and removes the entries from breadrumb view dropdown.

Comment: That's one approach. I would also point out that Contribute does not afford users the ability to create Public views - only Personal views. So basically, they'd be able to spam up your DB full of personal views if they felt like it, but it's not going to have a measurable impact on anyone else. If this is intended to be a security-through-obscurity thing though, you might want to just use the built-in security option in Advanced Settings -> Item-level Permissions -> Create and Edit Access.

Comment: That setting doesn't appear for a library.  I think it is only available to lists.

Comment: Ah yes, silly me. However, there is still the Content Approval route for libraries. A messy way to do it, but there it is.